# Safari Web Inspector stopped working on latest iOS for WebKit apps

Tags: ios, xcode, safari, webkit, web-inspector

Using [Safari Web Inspector](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007874-CH2-SW20) on a **WebKit** based app stopped working on **iOS** `16.4`.

This was properly working before.

More specifically, using the *iOS Simulator* or a *real device*, debugging a **WebKit** based app and from **Safari** on **macOS** accessing the **Develop** to inspect the app.

No difference at all if it is the *Simulator* or a *real device*; none seem to work, but inspecting **iOS-Safari** from **macOS-Safari** works as expected.

I already tried deleting and reinstalling the app, erasing the simulator, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a new property [isInspectable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/4111163-isinspectable) on `WKWebView`, `false` by default but turning it on will enable the inspector.

This works both for **iOS** and **macOS**, no need for the old way of using **KVO** on **macOS** with `developerExtrasEnabled` anymore.

## Available

- **iOS** `16.4`
- **macOS** `13.3`

## Turning it on

```swift
wkWebView.isInspectable = true
```

Comment: Are release builds can be inspected with it?

Comment: @Cy-4AH Release builds can be inspected, but the inspector needs to be activated from Safari, both for iOS and macOS.

Comment: This answer, thank you sir.

Comment: I am getting error `Cannot find 'webView' in scope`

Comment: @AbhaySingh Please share some more of your code or maybe even open a new question for it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to update your macOS or xcode try this

```
if webView.responds(to: Selector(("setInspectable:"))) {
    webView.perform(Selector(("setInspectable:")), with: true)
}
```

This worked for me on
`XCode -> 14.2 (14C18)`
`macOS -> 13.4 (22F66)`

Ref -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/76603043/12150745