# How to debug wkwebview in iOS 16.4.1 using XCode 14.2?

Tags: ios, swift, safari, wkwebview

- Environment:

1. MacOS: Monterey 12.6.1
2. XCode: 14.2
3. iOS: 16.4.1
4. Safari : 16.2 (17614.3.7.1.7, 17614)

- Question:

I want to debug my webview, and I open safari and nothing in the my device inspector.
Than I search the information, wkwebview change the default config.
Create new setting [(isInspectable)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/4111163-isinspectable) about wkwebview.
And I using the XCode 14.2 don't have this property.

```
if (@available(iOS 16.4, *)) {
     self.wkWebView.inspectable = YES; //Property 'inspectable' not found on object of type 'WKWebView *'
}
```

Have any idea to debug webview without upgrade my macOS and install XCode 14.3?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show the inspector within your WKWebView based desktop app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25200116/how-to-show-the-inspector-within-your-wkwebview-based-desktop-app)

Answer (score 8):

I also faced the same issue and this solution works for me.

```
if webView.responds(to: Selector(("setInspectable:"))) {
    webView.perform(Selector(("setInspectable:")), with: true)
}
```

After this we can debug the WKWebView in safari.

Comment: Yeah, this works for me My XCode is 14.2 (14C18)
and macOS is 13.4 (22F66)
Thanks a lot man you saved my life :)

Comment: where should I put this code?

Answer (score 1):

Considering the building environment before accessing the inspectable property, as below

```
#if __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 130300 || \
    __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 160400 || \
    __TV_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 160400
    if (@available(macOS 13.3, iOS 16.4, tvOS 16.4, *))
      self.wkWebView.inspectable = _webviewDebuggingEnabled;
#endif
```